# Cannot access hybris backoffice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am pursuing hybris training. In my hybris 2011, cannot access backoffice. Hybris administration console is accessible. It says "404 page not found". How to solve this?

Comment: How did you install Hybris? What URL are you using to open backoffice?

Comment: https://help.sap.com/viewer/4c33bf189ab9409e84e589295c36d96e/2105/en-US/8ace75c786691014a5e9dcafa29d5410.html?q=customizing%20b2c%20accelerator                                                                                I have installed as above.               I am trying to access backoffice in the following link.  https://localhost:9002/backoffice/login                                                                     It was working fine  till yesterday.

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. It arises due to some errors in trainingcore>resources>localization>trainingcore-locales_en.properties, where I have added some label names. I deleted them, ant clean all and then started server again.
note: ERROR [localhost-startStop-12] [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'backofficeWarmUpTypeFacadeCaches' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/backoffice-web-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException.

This error message was there in terminal when I was not able to access backoffice.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Using HAC. Go to Maintenance -> Cleanup-> TypeSystem, and click "Clear all orphaned types".
2. Using Ant. If you execute ant -p you will see a list of ant targets, and there look for the target "clearOrphanedTypes"
   clearOrphanedTypes: Clears orphaned types after system update.
   Syntax: ant clearOrphanedTypes [-DclearInstances=true/false -DclearDeployments=true/false].
   Default value for clearInstances is true, default value for clearDeployments is true